# Nuxt3+microcms+netlifyで作成したWEBサイト、ローカル環境でHydration children mismatchが出る原因を解明したい

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

現在以下の環境でWEBサイトを制作しています。

- node.js v18.19.0
- npm 10.2.3
- Nuxt@3.10.0
- microcms
- netlify

しかし特定のコード部分でHydration children mismatchが発生。
サーバーとクライアントで出力するDOMのズレが原因とのことで見比べてみたのですが、ＤＯＭズレはなし。
他に原因となる要因はあるのでしょうか。
microcmsの設定は https://blog.microcms.io/nuxt3-jamstack-blog/ を参照しました。

コードは下記です。

```
// ~/pages/blogs.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="">
            <div class="container">
        <h1 class="el_head">投稿一覧</h1>
        <ul class="bl_blogList">
        <li v-for="blog in data?.contents" :key="blog.id">
          <NuxtLink :to="`/${blog.id}`">
            <img :src="blog.eyecatch?.url || '/noimg.jpg'" :width="blog.eyecatch?.width" :height="blog.eyecatch?.height" alt="" />
            <h4>{{ blog.title }}</h4>
            <span class="el_blogLabel">{{ blog.category?.name }}</span>
            <span class="el_blogData">{{ dataFormat(blog.publishedAt ?? blog.createdAt) }}</span>
          </NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Blog } from "~~/types/blog";
import { dataFormat } from '~~/utils/dataFormat';
const { data } = await useMicroCMSGetList<Blog>({
  endpoint: "blogs",
});
</script>
```

```
// ~/types/blog.ts
import type { MicroCMSImage, MicroCMSListContent } from "microcms-js-sdk";
import type { Category } from "./category";

export type Blog = {
  title?: string;
  content?: string;
  eyecatch?: MicroCMSImage;
  category: (MicroCMSListContent & Category) | null;
};
```

該当するエラーログは下記。
ローカルの場合

```
chunk-UKZM2QLG.js?v=6ab75479:1502 [Vue warn]: Hydration children mismatch on 
<ul class="bl_blogList" data-v-inspector="components/bloglist.vue:3:5">
Server rendered element contains more child nodes than client vdom.
```

ulの中身を消してみてもエラーは消えませんが、上記のulタグを消すとエラーは消えます。ピンポイントでmismatch判定されているようです。

ちなみにnetlify上にデプロイしたあと、401エラーが出るのですが、上記が関係していることはありますか？
.envにある情報をnetlifyg側に設定しても解消しないので何かほかに原因があるとは思うのですが。

Answer (score 0):

色々と試しましたが
解決しないので、コード自体外すことにしました。
環境要因かもしれません。